# Error showing sending buttons as responses in Facebook messenger bot

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, dialogflow-es

I am building a Facebook messenger bot with api.ai integration. My api.ai agent is connected to a webhook - api.php. My challenge now is that I want to send a button response (formatted messages) to the bot through my webhook. 
I followed this doc -
https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook

And I did this in api.php but it not displaying the button

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
ob_start();
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$action = $request["result"]["action"];
$parameters = $request["result"]["parameters"];

$data =json_encode([
'speech' => "test",
'displayText' => "test",
'data' => "{
        'facebook': {
  'recipient':{
    'id':'USER_ID'
  },
  'message':{
    'attachment':{
      'type':'template',
      'payload':{
        'template_type':'button',
        'text':'What do you want to do next?',
        'buttons':[
          {
            'type':'web_url',
            'url':'https://petersapparel.parseapp.com',
            'title':'Show Website'
          },
          {
            'type':'postback',
            'title':'Start Chatting',
            'payload':'USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
    }
 }",
'source' => "source"
]);
echo $data;
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you really mean by, it is not displaying? Is it that the message isn't delivering at all? Can you post your stacktrace if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $qrString = "Date|Location|Category";
    $qrActions = "ActionSetDate|ActionSetLocation|ActionSetCategory";
    $webhookResponseArray['data']['facebook']['text'] = "Choose an action...";
    // make array of prompts and actions
    $qrArray = array();
    $actionArray = explode('|', $qrActions);
    $i = 0;
    $a = array();
    foreach (explode('|', $qrString) as $qrButton)
        {
        $a['content_type'] = 'text';
        $a['title'] = $qrButton;
        $a['payload'] = $actionArray[$i];
        $qrArray[] = $a;
        $i++;
        }
    $webhookResponseArray['data']['facebook']['quick_replies'] = $qrArray;
    // encode and send webhookResponseArray
```